# Kubernetes: StorageClass with local provisioner and StatefulSet kind

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volume-claims, kubernetes-statefulset

One of my pods has 'StatefulSet' kind with volumeClaimTemplates section referring to a StorageClass(SC) I created, see below.

SC:

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: local-storage
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
```

StatefulSet YAML with reference to above created SC:

```
volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: mydata
      spec:
        storageClassName: local-storage
        accessModes:
          - ReadWriteOnce
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 2Gi
```

As far as I am aware, a StatefulSet will create node specific PVCs without a need for explicit PV and PVC set up, I see that PV being created but the pod status is 'pending' with below warning.

> Warning  FailedScheduling  default-scheduler  0/4 nodes are available: 4 node(s) didn't find available persistent volumes to bind.

Note that I don't have a default StorageClass set up in the cluster, I believe that's not required for this scenario, is that correct?
Do we need to enable or configure anything for 'local' provisioner to work in the cluster?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out hard way that missing piece for this to work was PV set up.

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-loc-sc
spec:
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete
  storageClassName: local-storage 
  capacity:
    storage: 2Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  local:
    path: "/var/lib/test"
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - my-test-node-host-name
```

The FailedScheduling warning went away with PV, SC, and reference to the SC in StatefulSet pod YAML.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you need to go over [this document](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/sig-storage-local-static-provisioner/blob/master/docs/operations.md) for configuring the local volume static provisioner.

I would also suggest going over [the user guide](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/sig-storage-local-static-provisioner#user-guide) as there might be other steps needed to get this to properly work.

Comment: I have looked at the documentation and found out that 'local' provisioner has already been in place by default, so need to set it up again.